# SQL Subqueries throwing an error

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, subquery, syntax-error

I am trying to run this query

```
    SELECT        Name, Position, Salary
FROM            Employee
WHERE        (Salary =
                             (SELECT        MAX(Salary)
                               FROM            Employee))
```

However whenever I run it I get the following error

> Error Source: SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider
>   Error Message: There was an error parsing the query. [Token line
>   number = 1, Token line offset = 69, Token in error = SELECT]

I'm wondering if this is me not undertsanding how subqueries work although my tutor assures me that the statement I am trying to run is correct, could anyone shed some light on this situation, thanks.

Comment: Just one set of brackets too many

Comment: What version of the ADO .Net provider are you using?  I wonder if this is related to that library instead of SQL CE specifically.

Comment: My suggestion is to use SQL-Server Express if you can, the CE edition has some  limitations. (do try to resolve the issue in the meantime, as @Mike Fal suggests it may have something to do with ADO version).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for SQL Server:

```
SELECT Name, Position, Salary
FROM Employee E
   JOIN ( SELECT Max(Salary) as Sal FROM Employee ) M  ON E.Salary = M.Sal
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72492/3).

--EDIT

It sounds like you are using SQL Server CE which does not fully support nested sub queries.  Try something like this instead using the `IN` keyword:

```
SELECT e.Name, e.Position, e.Salary
FROM Employee e
WHERE e.Salary IN (SELECT MAX(Salary) as sal 
                   FROM Employee)
```

Comment: After trying this I get the message - "The Derived Table SQL construct or statement is not supported"

Comment: I still get the same error, I am using Visual Studio to connect to the database and it is only a compact local database stored on my memory stick for college, probably doesn't support the same as the full SQL server perhaps?

Comment: Which RDBMS?  Possible it doesn't support subqueries.

Comment: We are using MSSQL Server 2008, and using Visual studio to create the database and queries.

Answer (score 1):

Compact edition has obviously several limitations. You can try this one:

```
SELECT e.Name, e.Position, e.Salary
FROM Employee e
  LEFT JOIN Employee s
    ON s.Salary > e.Salary
WHERE s.Salary IS NULL ;
```

and this:

```
SELECT e.Name, e.Position, e.Salary
FROM Employee e
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM Employee s
        WHERE s.Salary > e.Salary
      ) ;
```

and this:

```
SELECT e.Name, e.Position, e.Salary
FROM Employee e
WHERE e.Salary IN 
      ( SELECT MAX(s.Salary)
        FROM Employee s
      ) ;
```

and this (maybe CE does not allow `GROUP BY` in subqueries/derived tables, or group by on the whole table):

```
SELECT e.Name, e.Position, e.Salary
FROM Employee e
WHERE e.Salary = 
      ( SELECT TOP (1) s.Salary
        FROM Employee s
        ORDER BY s.Salary DESC
      ) ;
```